# How can I change the titlebar height in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Pictures are worth a thousand words, so I will explain my question with a couple of screenshots.

- [This is how Firefox looks by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx4Wc.png)
- [This is how Firefox looks when the menu bar is always visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTL07.png)

As you can see, the tabs and the tab buttons do not position themselves underneath the window controls (minimise, maximise, and close buttons) by default. This is because the titlebar is not tall enough. Setting the menu bar to display permanently increases the titlebar height, and allows the tabs and tab buttons to be placed underneath those window controls.

Now, I really hate the way Firefox behaves by default. I feel like it's completely wasting space, and forces me to have a much smaller area for my tabs than I should be able to. But it doesn't even feel like it's trying to be minimal, because if that's what they were aiming for, they could easily have made the titlebar even smaller instead of having a large gap above the tabs.

What I want to know is: how can I change the titlebar height?

Really, I would like to be able to use Firefox in two different modes:

1. Have the tabs and tab buttons positioned to the left of the window controls. This would be similar to the default behaviour, except with a *smaller* titlebar height, so there isn't a ponitless gap above the tabs.
2. Have the tabs and tab buttons positioned underneath the window controls, but *without* needing to have the menu bar visible. In other words, a slightly taller titlebar height.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

PS: As an aside, is it possible to disable the background/blur behind the menu bar? This isn't too important, though.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Both links point to the same image, so we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you have a different (old?) version of Firefox. In my version the tabs are placed next to the controls. Maybe you just update to latest version (currently 52.0.1).

[image: Firefox tab placement in version 52.0.1]

PS: Choose a theme and post again to see if the blur behind the menubar went away.

[image: Choosing a theme (Pastel Gradient in this case)]

[image: No blur on menubar when using a theme]